# POI reading cell background color

Tags: apache-poi

I am using POI 3.8 version and trying to read the background color of a cell in an excel sheet (XLS). Ideally I wanted to copy this cell with styles to a different sheet. When I did a **cloneFrom(..)** method, its not copying the correct colors to the target sheet.

When I tried to read the cell's background color separately, I am not getting the correct RGB value. If I could get the correct RGB value I can create a custom palette and set the same to the target sheet's cell.

Is there a correct way of reading the background color from a cell?

I have tried the  following

```
cell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor()
cell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor().getTriplet()
```

The above line should give me RGB value of 159/200/222, but is giving me an incorrect value of 51/204/204.

Could someone please help on the same. I have already checked this forum for all possible answers and still could not get what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that HSSF uses a color palette (essentially an array of colors) to define its RGB values. So the background color is actually an index into the palette. Here is some code to get the actual rgb values of the cell's background color:

```
    CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
    short colorIdx = style.getFillForegroundColor();
    HSSFPalette palette = ((HSSFWorkbook) wb).getCustomPalette();
    HSSFColor color = palette.getColor(colorIdx);
    short [] triplet = color.getTriplet();
    // triplet will contain the actual rgb values
```

In your output spreadsheet, you have to add a custom color to the palette. If there is an empty space in your output's palette, you can use HSSFPalette.addColor. Otherwise, you will have to replace an unused existing color using HSSFPalette.setColorAtIndex. Once you add the custom color, you use CellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor to set the cell's background color, passing in the index of the custom color you just created.

If you can use an XSSF (xlsx) file instead of an HSSF (xls) file, you would not need to fool around with a color palette. You can use actual rgb values.

Comment: I tried this piece of code and it gave me HSSFColor.AUTOMATIC.index value which is 64 and the triplet I got is [0,0,0] which is white. When I tried it as a foreground color I got the same triplet [51,204,204] which is wrong. Any help on this is very much appreciated

Comment: I tried this code before I posted it, and it did work for me. If you want to go to my profile, my email address is there, and you can email me the xls file and identify the cell for which you need the background color. I will write some code showing you exactly how to get it.

Comment: I was unable to get your email id from the profile. To brief my request is I have a excel sheet (xls) which has one one cell which got filled with the background color RGB[159,200,222]. I am trying to read this excel sheet using POI 3.8 API and trying to print the RGB color of the cell. I tried the above code and I was not able to get the RGB color as set. So please help to solve this issue.

Comment: You can reach me at hschutzman@alum.mit.edu In order to make sure I send you code that works, you need to send me your Excel file, and tell me which cell you want to get the color of.

Comment: I have sent you the email. Please help

Comment: I have the same problem now mentioned in this email. Does email address hschutzman@alum.mit.edu still works?