# Java poi read cell color, but could not succeed

Tags: apache-poi

This questions is duplicated with the [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106949/poi-reading-cell-background-color), but the thread has no final answer but leaving an email address.

My problem is that I could not read a colored cell in the xlsx sheet, it always return me color code 64 whatever white, yellow or green.

Any valid example code to show me how to read xlsx sheet's cell filled color?[image]

> 

```
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);

 
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

  
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    int lastCellNum = 0;
    int temp =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastRowNum; i++) {
        XSSFRow rowValue = sheet.getRow(i);
        
        temp = rowValue.getLastCellNum();
        if (lastCellNum < temp)
            lastCellNum = temp;
    }
    System.out.println(" For "+lastRowNum+ " rows, the maximum last cell number is:"+ lastCellNum);
    System.out.println(" ");
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        for(int i=0; i < lastRowNum; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            XSSFRow rowValue = sheet.getRow(i);
            XSSFCell cell = rowValue.getCell(j);
            if (cell!= null) {
                XSSFColor colorCode = cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
                if(colorCode!=null){
                    System.out.println("row " + i + ", column " + j + ", color is" + Arrays.toString(colorCode.getRgb()));
                }
            }
            System.out.println("row " + i + ", column " + j + ", "+"value is " + cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on if the colors are really cell fill colors. If so, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66689752/getting-the-background-color-of-a-xssf-cell/66691103#66691103 works for me using `XSSF` as well as using `HSSF`.  But if the colors are results of conditional formatting, then this cannot work. Please check.

Comment: The problem is that the editor uses Chinese domestic office suit was to edit xlsx file. So normal method sometime may not function.